# Converting a function with early return to a function template

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have a function template, which has a type template parameter, and returns an optional. The function template has several explicit specializations:

```
template <typename>
std::optional<int> foo();

template <>
std::optional<int> foo<char>() {
    return {};
}

template <>
std::optional<int> foo<short>() {
    return 1;
}

template <>
std::optional<int> foo<int>() {
    return 2;
}
```

(Note: in my real code, functions doesn't have a fixed return value)

Now, I have a function, which calls these, and early returns if a `foo` function call returns an engaged optional. For example:

```
std::optional<int> call_them() {
    if (auto o = foo<char>(); o) {
        return o;
    }
    if (auto o = foo<short>(); o) {
        return o;
    }
    return foo<int>();
}
```

I'd like to convert this function to a function template, so the type list can be anything, while keeping the exact same semantics. The best I could come up with is this:

```
template <typename ...TYPES>
struct Types {};

template <typename TYPE>
bool call_one(std::optional<int> &o) {
    std::optional<int> x = foo<TYPE>();
    if (x) {
        o = x;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

template <typename... TYPES>
std::optional<int> call_them(Types<TYPES...>) {
    std::optional<int> o;
    (call_one<TYPES>(o) || ...);
    return o;
}
```

So then I can use `call_them(Types<char, short, int>())`, and this will calculate the same value as the non-template `call_them` (and has the early return property as well). My problem is that this doesn't have the exact same semantics as the non-template version, as the optional `o` is default constructed, and then the assignment operator is used to update its value. But the original version never used the default constructor, but used the copy/move constructor the create the return value. Is it possible to create a templated `call_them` solution which behaves like the non-template version?

(Note: in my real code, the problem is more complex, and I don't use `std::optional`, but some other custom class with a similar semantics. It was the easiest to explain this problem with `std::optional`.)

Comment: Maybe one step back first. What do you want your code to do?  Do you really want the result of `call_them` to be an `optional<int>` and not a `bool`.

Comment: Note that `if (auto o = foo<char>(); o)` can be shortened to `if (auto o = foo<char>())`. And if you're not against one line if statements, you can have `if (auto o = foo<char>()) return o;`

Comment: Seems like a candidate for monadic or_else from C++23 or Sy Brand's optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use array of function pointers:

```
template <typename... TYPES>
std::optional<int> call_them(Types<TYPES...>) {
    constexpr auto funcs = std::array{&foo<TYPES>...};
    for (auto f : funcs) {
        if (auto o = f(); o) {
            return o;
        }
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice idea, I somehow didn't consider using a `for`, because it's not a compile time construct, and I wanted to make sure that the compiled code is surely similarly efficient as the original one (I mean, the compiler surely won't use a loop, but put the function calls one after the other, just like the original version. But it is not a very important thing). Tiny correction: I think you need to use `foo` instead of `call_one`.

Comment: @geza: you might avoid the loop with "recursion"...

Answer (score 2):

you could use a recursive approach and hope the compiler inlines all the invocations, msvc seem to inline it on O2, while gcc and clang inline it on O3. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ohf3naMMb) (check out bar() assembly)

```
template<typename T>
std::optional<int> call_them_impl()
{
    if (auto o = foo<T>(); o)
    {
        return o;
    }
    return foo<int>();
}

template<typename First, typename Second, typename ...TYPES>
std::optional<int> call_them_impl()
{
    if (auto o = foo<First>(); o)
    {
        return o;
    }
    return call_them_impl<Second, TYPES...>();
}

template <typename... TYPES>
std::optional<int> call_them(Types<TYPES...>) {
    return call_them_impl<TYPES...>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you're on C++23 you can do this:

```cpp
namespace detail
{
template<typename T>
std::optional<int> call_them()
{
    return foo<T>();
}

template<typename First, typename Second, typename ...TYPES>
std::optional<int> call_them()
{
    return foo<First>().or_else(call_them<Second, TYPES...>);
}
} //namespace detail

template<typename ...Args>
std::optional<int> call_them(Types<Args...>)
{
    return detail::call_them<Args...>();
}
```

`or_else` can be replaced with a ternary of if, e.g. this way:

```cpp
    std::optional<int> ret = foo<First>();
    return  ret.has_value() ? ret : detail::call_them<Second, TYPES...>();
```